# What is a good approach to update a Solr schema for multi purposes/usecases?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, multicore

I am using solr 4.10. Its schema is the one provided by apache nutch as it stores indexes of crawled data by Nutch. Now I have to index a user informations in index also so that we can search for users. For that I have to change schema. I have two options in this case

1. Create a new schema file and use solr in multi core form
2. Update existing schema file and add news fields in this schema.

What is the best approach for that task? If there is any other option other than above two, then please give that option and guide for better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is use a specific core for each different scope information. It makes the index less complex and more specific to a better understanding and high performance search.
If you use the same core to index information of lots of different scopes you will make the index big and complex affecting the performance.
Other important benefit of split your index in different cores is that you can use different indexing strategies to each core.

Comment: Can you explain  what ado you mean by indexing strategies ?

Comment: You can use different indexing strategies to each different core. For example: if you have an e-commerce and need to index products and its lots of prices you can split it into two indexes, one of products and the other of prices. You can use a strategy of atomic updates to prices for example and a full document update to products. It permits you to use different indexing intervals to each core.

Comment: Other important benefit of using different cores is that you can use different cache strategies for each one.